# Functional equation in real numbers - Prove that f(x) = x

Tags: functional-equations, functional-inequalities

The function $f$ is defined over the real numbers and satisfies $f(x) \le x$ and $f(x+y) \le f(x) + f(y)$ for all real $x,y$. Prove that $f(x) = x$ for every real number $x$.

I have tried plugging in some values. Plugging $x=0$ we get $f(0) \le 0$ and $f(0)\le2f(0) \implies f(0)\ge0$ which together imply that $f(0)=0\\$.
To prove the given statement how can I proceed further?

Edit: I tried putting $y=-x$ from which I got
$f(0) = 0 \le f(x) +f(-x)\le x + (-x)=0$
Therefore $f(x)+f(-x)=0 \implies f(-x)=-f(x)$.

How can I use this to show $f(x)=x $ ?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Now that you know that $f(0) = 0$, try getting an information out of it that's valid for any $x$ with a well-chosen $y$ that gets you an inequality the other way. (I'm trying to only give a hint, hence the long-winded sentence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** By hypothesis, $f(-x)\le -x$. But you know that $f(-x)=-f(x)$, so...